# Cannot save document in Xpages when there are multiple FileDownload controls and a certain number of deletions have occurred

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino

I have an XPage that has multiple FileUpload and FileDownload controls on it.  The FileDownload controls allow deletion.  This works well sometimes, but other times it doesn't.

The problem manifests when saving the document.

This is the XPage source:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" xmlns:xc="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/custom">
    <xp:this.data>
        <xp:dominoDocument var="document1"></xp:dominoDocument>
    </xp:this.data>
    <xp:div id="divFLControl1">
        <xp:label value="Car photo" id="label25"></xp:label>
        <xp:fileUpload id="flUpload1" styleClass="file">
            <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{document1.photoCar}]]></xp:this.value>
            <xp:this.accept><![CDATA[#{javascript:"image/bmp,image/jpeg,image/png,application/pdf,text/plain,application/msword,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document,video/mpeg,video/x-msvideo,video/mp4,video/x-ms-wmv"}]]></xp:this.accept>
            <xp:eventHandler event="onchange" submit="true" refreshMode="partial" disableValidators="true" refreshId="divFLControl1"></xp:eventHandler>
        </xp:fileUpload>
        <xp:message id="message1" for="flUpload1"></xp:message>
        <xp:fileDownload rows="30" id="fileDownload1" displayLastModified="false" hideWhen="true" styleClass="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered" displayType="false" allowDelete="true">
            <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{document1.photoCar}]]></xp:this.value>
        </xp:fileDownload>
    </xp:div>
    <xp:div id="divFLControl2">
        <xp:label value="Bus Photo" id="label1"></xp:label>
        <xp:fileUpload id="fileUpload2" styleClass="file" value="#{document1.photoBus}">
            <xp:this.accept><![CDATA[#{javascript:"image/bmp,image/jpeg,image/png,application/pdf,text/plain,application/msword,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document,video/mpeg,video/x-msvideo,video/mp4,video/x-ms-wmv"}]]></xp:this.accept>
            <xp:eventHandler event="onchange" submit="true" refreshMode="partial" disableValidators="true" refreshId="divFLControl2"></xp:eventHandler>
        </xp:fileUpload>
        <xp:message id="message2" for="flUpload2"></xp:message>
        <xp:fileDownload rows="30" id="fileDownload2" displayLastModified="false" hideWhen="true" styleClass="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered" displayType="false" allowDelete="true" value="#{document1.photoBus}">
        </xp:fileDownload>
    </xp:div>

    <xp:button value="Save" id="button1">
        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="complete" immediate="false" save="true"></xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:button>
</xp:view>
```

There are a certain number of steps that can be followed, and then the Save button gets an error.

These are the steps:

1. Add an attachment to the first field, delete it, and then add an attachment again.
2. Add an attachment to the second field, delete it, and then add an attachment to it again.
3. Click Save.

This is the error:

```
Unexpected runtime error
The runtime has encountered an unexpected error.
Error source
Page Name:/claim26.xsp

Exception
Error saving data source document1
▼ Stack Trace
javax.faces.FacesException: Error saving data source document1
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:102)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.phase(LifecycleImpl.java:210)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:96)
    com.ibm.xsp.controller.FacesControllerImpl.execute(FacesControllerImpl.java:256)
    com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.serviceView(FacesServlet.java:231)
    com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.serviceView(FacesServletEx.java:157)
    com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:163)
    com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.service(FacesServletEx.java:138)
    com.ibm.xsp.webapp.DesignerFacesServlet.service(DesignerFacesServlet.java:103)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:600)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.invokeServlet(NSFComponentModule.java:1352)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$AdapterInvoker.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:877)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$ServletInvoker.doService(ComponentModule.java:820)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.doService(ComponentModule.java:589)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.doService(NSFComponentModule.java:1336)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doServiceInternal(NSFService.java:725)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doService(NSFService.java:515)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.doService(LCDEnvironment.java:357)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.service(LCDEnvironment.java:313)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.bridge.http.engine.XspCmdManager.service(XspCmdManager.java:272)
com.ibm.xsp.FacesExceptionEx: Error saving data source document1
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.save(FacesUtil.java:585)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.save(FacesUtil.java:552)
    com.ibm.xsp.component.UIViewRootEx.save(UIViewRootEx.java:1200)
    com.ibm.xsp.component.UIViewRootEx.save(UIViewRootEx.java:1189)
    com.ibm.xsp.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:78)
    javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:324)
    com.ibm.xsp.component.UIEventHandler.broadcast(UIEventHandler.java:366)
    com.ibm.xsp.component.UIViewRootEx.broadcast(UIViewRootEx.java:1669)
    javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:307)
    javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:428)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:94)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.phase(LifecycleImpl.java:210)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:96)
    com.ibm.xsp.controller.FacesControllerImpl.execute(FacesControllerImpl.java:256)
    com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.serviceView(FacesServlet.java:231)
    com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.serviceView(FacesServletEx.java:157)
    com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:163)
    com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.service(FacesServletEx.java:138)
    com.ibm.xsp.webapp.DesignerFacesServlet.service(DesignerFacesServlet.java:103)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:600)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.invokeServlet(NSFComponentModule.java:1352)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$AdapterInvoker.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:877)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$ServletInvoker.doService(ComponentModule.java:820)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.doService(ComponentModule.java:589)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.doService(NSFComponentModule.java:1336)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doServiceInternal(NSFService.java:725)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doService(NSFService.java:515)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.doService(LCDEnvironment.java:357)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.service(LCDEnvironment.java:313)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.bridge.http.engine.XspCmdManager.service(XspCmdManager.java:272)
java.lang.NullPointerException
    com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.wrapped.DominoRichTextItem.updateMultipartRelated(DominoRichTextItem.java:1968)
    com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.wrapped.DominoRichTextItem.addMimeToStream(DominoRichTextItem.java:1931)
    com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.wrapped.DominoRichTextItem.updateRTMime(DominoRichTextItem.java:1911)
    com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.wrapped.DominoRichTextItem.updateRichTextItem(DominoRichTextItem.java:1581)
    com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.wrapped.DominoDocument.applyChangesToDoc(DominoDocument.java:2026)
    com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.wrapped.DominoDocument.applyChanges(DominoDocument.java:1995)
    com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.wrapped.DominoDocument.save(DominoDocument.java:1356)
    com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.DominoDocumentData.doSaveDocument(DominoDocumentData.java:684)
    com.ibm.xsp.model.AbstractDocumentDataSource.save(AbstractDocumentDataSource.java:76)
    com.ibm.xsp.model.AbstractDataSource._saveData(AbstractDataSource.java:553)
    com.ibm.xsp.model.AbstractDataSource.save(AbstractDataSource.java:534)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.save(FacesUtil.java:577)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.save(FacesUtil.java:552)
    com.ibm.xsp.component.UIViewRootEx.save(UIViewRootEx.java:1200)
    com.ibm.xsp.component.UIViewRootEx.save(UIViewRootEx.java:1189)
    com.ibm.xsp.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:78)
    javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:324)
    com.ibm.xsp.component.UIEventHandler.broadcast(UIEventHandler.java:366)
    com.ibm.xsp.component.UIViewRootEx.broadcast(UIViewRootEx.java:1669)
    javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:307)
    javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:428)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:94)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.phase(LifecycleImpl.java:210)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:96)
    com.ibm.xsp.controller.FacesControllerImpl.execute(FacesControllerImpl.java:256)
    com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.serviceView(FacesServlet.java:231)
    com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.serviceView(FacesServletEx.java:157)
    com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:163)
    com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.service(FacesServletEx.java:138)
    com.ibm.xsp.webapp.DesignerFacesServlet.service(DesignerFacesServlet.java:103)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:600)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.invokeServlet(NSFComponentModule.java:1352)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$AdapterInvoker.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:877)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$ServletInvoker.doService(ComponentModule.java:820)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.doService(ComponentModule.java:589)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.doService(NSFComponentModule.java:1336)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doServiceInternal(NSFService.java:725)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doService(NSFService.java:515)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.doService(LCDEnvironment.java:357)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.service(LCDEnvironment.java:313)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.bridge.http.engine.XspCmdManager.service(XspCmdManager.java:272)
```

When there is one FileUpload and FileDownload control, the Save button works without issue.

When there are two, as in the posted XPage source, adding an attachment to the first field, deleting it, adding again, then the Save button works without issue.

**Additional information**
Through testing it seems to be narrowed down to using org.openntf.domino.xsp.XspLibrary in Xsp Properties, for the line xsp.library.depends.

```
xsp.library.depends=com.ibm.xsp.extlib.library,com.ibm.xsp.extlib.relational.library
#xsp.library.depends=com.ibm.xsp.extlib.library,com.ibm.xsp.extlib.relational.library,org.openntf.domino.xsp.XspLibrary
```

This line is also in Xsp Properties:

```
org.openntf.domino.xsp=godmode,khan,marcel
```

Comment: Try removing the OpenNTF Domino API "godmode" setting from xsp.properties and see if it then works

Comment: Thanks @Per, doing that does help with the code above.

Unfortunately that code is much simplified and the actual code I use is heavily reliant on godmode it would seem, since it won't save even if attachments haven't been deleted.

Comment: so it is the OpenNTF Domino API 'godmode' that is the cause of the error, it seems?

Comment: It seems that way @Per. I've had to keep in the godmode, and code in my own fileDownload control to delay attachment deletions until after the document is saved.